# Cambiar tema en dispositivos móviles

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

Me gustaría saber si es posible cambia el color de los botones virtuales con JavaScript o alguna librería y posteriormente visualizarlo desde mi dispositivo móvil con dicho color desde el navegador web, gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no es posible de ninguna manera.

Te lo planteo así: Básicamente quieres saber si una aplicación web que se muestra en una app de tu Android sea capaz de modificar elementos y estilos que le corresponden al sistema nativo.

Las aplicaciones web que se muestren en tus dispositivos móviles difícilmente van a cambiar elementos del sistema.

Lo que puedes hacer es en una app móvil crear un vinculo que te lleve a las opciones del sistema donde este la personalización, tal como lo hacen algunas apps que solicitan permisos de accesibilidad

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta compañero 